# Render only if {{variable}} is defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

Say I have some text such as:

```
The data is ready. Here it is: {{something}}
```

I would like to only render that line if `something` is not `undefined`. How can I do that?

In case it helps, here is that line in a broader context:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">

<input type="text" ng-model="selected" 
typeahead="name_and_uid as item.name_and_uid for item in items | 
filter:{name_and_uid: $viewValue} | limitTo:16" 
typeahead-on-select='onSelect($item, $model, $label)' class="form-control">

The data is ready. Here it is: {{name_and_uid}}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

where `{{name_and_uid}}` is only defined after a selection is done.

Currently, I get `"The data is ready. Here it is:"` before making a selection. I only want that to be rendered once I type in and make a selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define in your scope:

```
   $scope.isDefined = function(v) {
            return angular.isDefined(v);
        };
```

And then

```
<div ng-show="isDefined(name_and_uid)">
    The data is ready. Here it is: {{name_and_uid}}
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the inputs `ng-model` length is 0 initially, you can use `ng-show` to only render that line when `$scope.selected` is greater then zero.

```
<div ng-show="selected.length > 0">
    <span>The data is ready. Here it is: {{name_and_uid}}</span>
</div>
```